# How to detach child_process from a node.js one?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to execute a shell command starting a long-running script from node and have the node process exit. For example, this keeps the node process running:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('gedit &', function() {
});
```

While I'd like it to exit just after gedit starts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always exit hard by putting `process.exit(0)` right after the exec call.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all the exec/spawn calls will be executed by that time?

Comment: I believe that dispatching the exec command to the OS is synchronous, so yes.